# Restoring deleted records using apex?

Tags: apex

Does anyone have any idea how to restore deleted records,normally deleted records store in recyclebin we can retrive from recycle even we deleted records from recyclebin how can we restore records using apex code?

Answer (score 13):

In every object there is one field `ISDeleted` when you delete records it get true. You need to set it false.

**Update**: Thanks @Ratan for suggestion. You can also try this method .

[Undelete](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_examples_undelete.htm)

```
Account a = new Account(Name='Trump');
insert(a);
insert(new Contact(LastName='Carter',AccountId=a.Id));
delete a;

    Account[] savedAccts = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Name = 'Trump' ALL ROWS]; 
    try {
        undelete savedAccts;
    } catch (DmlException e) {
        // Process exception here
    }
```

Comment: or like this.. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_examples_undelete.htm

Comment: Hi @Tushar Sharma i tried this code but i m getting error "Field is not writeable: Account.IsDeleted ".

Comment: @user123 i have also update another solution . You can check that too.

Comment: @Tushar Sharma:you are updated code working here we are retrive records from recycle bin when we delete records from recycle bin it won't getting records.my requirement is even we deleted records from recyclebin records will be restore using apex.

Comment: @user123 we use `ALL ROWS` to reterive record from recycle bin. Please check if your record  exist in recycle bin

Comment: Recycle bin empty

Comment: @user123 sorry in that case you cannot retrieve the records. You need to raise case to Salesforce to get them back.

Comment: @Tushar Sharma: Any other option to get deleted records using apex.

Comment: @user123 no you can't get them.

Answer (score 1):

Check out how [Using the Recycle Bin](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=home_delete.htm) works (emphasis mine):

> The Recycle Bin link in the sidebar lets you view and restore recently deleted records for **15 days before they are permanently deleted**. Your Recycle Bin record limit is 25 times the Megabytes (MBs) in your storage. For example, if your organization has 1 GB of storage then your limit is 25 times 1000 MB or 25,000 records. **If your organization reaches its Recycle Bin limit, Salesforce automatically removes the oldest records if they have been in the Recycle Bin for at least two hours.**

The same is true from `Apex`, you can only recover records for 15 days (unless you open a case with support). If you want to recover deleted records, you must `undelete` them as follows:

```
undelete [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE IsDeleted = true ALL ROWS];
```

Note that records can be "hard deleted" even before the 15 day period is up. The main ways that this can happen are if someone calls `Database.emptyRecycleBin`, manually emptying the `Recycle Bin` through the UI, or using the `Bulk API`, which has a hard delete option.

Comment: doesn't using Data Loader Delete on lots of records also push aside (hard delete) older items in the recycle bin ?

Comment: @crop1645 *If your organization reaches its Recycle Bin limit, Salesforce automatically removes the oldest records if they have been in the Recycle Bin for at least two hours.* I would think no based on the wording, since the operation woudl ostensibly complete within two hours. I have not used it much so I cannot confirm.

Comment: i was thinking about the 15 day rule that isn't always the case as you pointed out; i know when I use Data Loader' delete, I get a warning message saying that the recycle bin may not be big enough to recover the records being deleted